# DateTimeFormatter is being too strict on parsing single-digit parts

Tags: java, parsing, java-8, datetime-format

I have a format `MM/dd/yyyy`, so everything formatted is with leading ZERO on single digit. The problem is that on parsing I want to be able to parse both `"11/25/2018"` and `"5/25/2018"`, but formatting should always return leading zeros.

I've tried using different `ResolverStyle` options without any luck.

Building my own specific format seems unreasonable, when you think, that it was working out of the box using `SimpleDateFormat`.

Would appreciate any idea, that does not involve making formatter from scratch using `FormatterBuilder`

Comment: your question is not clear? Do you need leading zeros when there's only one single digit?

Comment: I need to be able to parse with single digit (like 5/24/2018), but always format to two digits (like 05/24/2018). I've edited question, to be more clear :-)

Comment: Sometimes java.time forces us into more precision than the old and poorly designed date and time classes did. It’s usually an advantage since it leads to code that conveys its intention more precisely. Here you have different requirements for parsing and for formatting. Expressing this fact with two different formatters in your code doesn’t seem to be a drawback to me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use two different formats, `M/d/yyyy` for parsing, and `MM/dd/yyyy` for printing. The former will accept both single and double digit months and days, while the latter will always print double-digits, with leading zero if necessary.

```
SimpleDateFormat parseFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat printFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

Date date1 = parseFormat.parse("4/5/2010");
Date date2 = parseFormat.parse("04/05/2010");
String output1 = printFormat.format(date1);
String output2 = printFormat.format(date2);
// output1 and output2 will be the same
```

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Which was already the one that was asked about. Using two instances of `DateTimeFormatter` is the correct approach.

Answer (score 8):

You could use the `appendOptional()` in Java 8 time API

```
DateTimeFormatter ALL_POSSIBLE_DATE_FORMAT = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy"))
            .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(("M/dd/yyyy")))
            .toFormatter();

System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("11/25/2018", ALL_POSSIBLE_DATE_FORMAT));
System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("5/25/2018", ALL_POSSIBLE_DATE_FORMAT));
```

Output:

2018-11-25

2018-05-25

Comment: The problem with this one, is that since both are optional, formatter.parse with any String returns TemporalAccessor without any exception. Only LocalDate.from/parse are throwing Exceptions.

But still it seems cleaner, then just using separate formats for formatting and parsing :-)

Comment: Isn't that a big loss since the old SimpleDateFormat? By default it is still parsing single digits when `MM` or `dd` was provided as the format. I do not see the reason for this re versal for as long as the number is bounded by literals. Having to specify separate pattern definitions for reading and parsing is cumbersome ...

Answer (score 6):

Use the `M/d/yyyy` format, because leading zeroes are ignored. `MM/dd/yyyy` implies that exactly two digits are required including the possible leading zero.

```
    DateTimeFormatter parseformat =
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/yyyy");

    DateTimeFormatter outputformat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

For the code segment

```
    String d1 = "1/1/2018";
    String d2 = "02/29/2016";
    String d3 = "4/01/2018";

    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(d1, parseformat);
    System.out.println(date.format(outputformat));
    date = LocalDate.parse(d2, parseformat);
    System.out.println(date.format(outputformat));
    date = LocalDate.parse(d3, parseformat);
    System.out.println(date.format(outputformat));
```

I ended up with

```
01/01/2018
02/29/2016
04/01/2018
```

as expected.

See the [SimpleDateFormat documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) for time patterns and how they are parsed; note that "Pattern letters are usually repeated, as their number determines the exact presentation" and that "For parsing, the number of pattern letters is ignored unless it's needed to separate two adjacent fields" (here you are separating two adjacent fields).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use M/d/yyyy. It will work with both single and double digits. When you use MM/dd you tell it to strictly use two digits.

That's from the docs:

> Number: If the count of letters is one, **then the value is output using
>   the minimum number of digits** and without padding. Otherwise, the count
>   of digits is used as the width of the output field, with the value
>   zero-padded as necessary. The following pattern letters have
>   constraints on the count of letters. Only one letter of 'c' and 'F'
>   can be specified. Up to two letters of 'd', 'H', 'h', 'K', 'k', 'm',
>   and 's' can be specified. Up to three letters of 'D' can be specified.

Comment: this only solves parsing problems, but not formatting ones. I want to use the same formatter to parse both cases, but format with leading zeros

Comment: @Qbix No, you should use 2 different formatters. Any reason why you can't?

Comment: Because it's cleaner for me to use one format that behaves alright with two digits, and handles missing zeros, when data from other app is sending it just a little malformed.

And again - it was handled alright with old, good SampleDateFormat

Comment: Don't get me wrong. I get it, that sometimes you want to have strict checking. It may also be the default option. But no such option seems just wrong for me, so I thought, that I might've missed it :-)